# my React App is not sending message to console

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am following a tutorial in order to understand how to connect the express routes that I have written to a react app.

The code, as I best understand it, is supposed to work as follows

**App.js**

```
import axios from "axios"
import React, { useState } from "react"
import "./App.css"

function App() {
    const [ name, setName ] = useState("")
    const [ home, setHome ] = useState("")

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:4000/home").then(function(response) {
            setHome(response.data)
        })
    }, [])

    async function postName(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        try {
            await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/post_name", {
                name
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <form onSubmit={postName}>
                <input type="text" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
                <button type="submit">Send Name</button>
            </form>
            {home}
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

the body above has a submit form that takes text inputted by the user, then on submit the form calls the async function postName. postName utilizes the built in function axios.post which fetches the url corresponding to the url/express_route my index.js is using and passes in the object name which I created at the top of the function in my useState.

In the **index.js**

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const port = 4000
const cors = require("cors")

// npm init
// npm i express cors nodemon
// they add a handy req.body object to our req,
// containing a Javascript
//  object representing the payload sent with the request

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())

app.get("/", cors(), async (req, res) => {
    res.send("This is working")
})
app.get("/home", cors(), async (req, res) => {
    res.send("This is the data for the home page")
})

app.post("/post_name", async (req, res) => {
    let { name } = req.body
    console.log(name)
})
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

we have an async function app.post which is meant to deal with the express route we set up in the axios function  and then prints the submitted name to console. I am able to get both of them running. I have nodemon, express axios and cors installed to allow for communication between the different urls. What am I missing why is this happening.

Comment: Is the express server running?  What happens when you ping it from the terminal?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are not seeing the name in browser console right? If so, check your terminal because your name will be printed on your terminal since you are printing the name in server side.

Comment: @Javokhir I am not seeing the name on the console, I don't want the name to appear on the browser

Comment: @MattMorgan I see my app.Listen prompt, indicating to me the express server is running, but nothing is passed in the console

Comment: Only thing I see missing is a response for the `/post_name` route. You should at least add `res.sendStatus(204)` but you should still have seen the result from `console.log(name)` in your terminal. Do you see the request sent successfully from the browser? Use the dev tools _Network_ panel to see what's going on

Comment: @Phil the problem turned out to be with the cache!